# Button position on map - Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, maps

I'm using Windows Phone 8 (Silverlight) and control Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.Map. How can I position the button, to be on the bottom right corner of the map. 
I have tried:

```
var grid = new Grid
{
     HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
     VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch
};
var button = new Button
{
     Content = "button",
     HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right,
     VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,    
};
grid.Children.Add(centerButton);
var mapOverlay = new MapOverlay
{
      Content = grid
};
var mapLayer = new MapLayer {mapOverlay};
map.Layers.Add(mapLayer);
```

but it still stays on top left only.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could solve this in another way. Your map control is placed on a view in some container, just add your button in the same container and try to place it correctly there. SO not as a map layer... example if your map is inside a grid, just add the button also in the same grid but after the map so that it will be placed on top.

Answer (score 0):

```
var grid = new Grid()
 {
  HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right,
  VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,    
 };
var button = new Button
{
     Content = "button",         
};
grid.Children.Add(button);
var mapOverlay = new MapOverlay
{
      Content = grid
};
var mapLayer = new MapLayer {mapOverlay};
map.Layers.Add(mapLayer);
```

Comment: It didn't help, it's still in the same position, but I resolved my issue with @Depechie idea, I added button to the same grid as map.